# Nullable object must have a value in mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

When I run the website and I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'

I have `Duzenle` controller and this included below codes:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Sube")]
public ActionResult Duzenle()
{
    var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
    var kullanici = UserGetter.GetUser();
    var subeId = kullanici.SubeId.Value; // exception is thrown here
    var kasaRaporu = db.KasaRaporu
        .Where(kr => kr.SubeId == subeId).ToList()
        .Where(kr => kr.Tarih.Date == date).FirstOrDefault();

    if (kasaRaporu != null)
    {
        return View(kasaRaporu);
    }

    kasaRaporu = KasaRaporuCreator.Create(subeId);
    return View(kasaRaporu);
}
```

The exception is thrown in this line:

```
var subeId = kullanici.SubeId.Value;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Obviously, `kullanici.SubeId` is `null`. Why it is `null` we can't tell without knowing your database.

Comment: @Emrah what do you want to do if `SubeId` is null? Why call `.Value` if it can be null? If you want to pass null values to `.Where(kr.SubeId == subeId)` don't call `.Value` at all. If you don't want to execute the query, use `if( kullanici.SubeId.HasValue){...}` to execute the query only if it has a value

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `kullanici.SubeId` is `null`. When you try to access `Value` of a `null` nullable, you will get this exception. Check the `GetUser` method and make sure the `SubeId` is not `null` when it is returned.